# Created local database programatically but I cannot create tables in it?

Tags: c#, database, local, mdf

I have been looking for a solution but I couldn't find anything.

I have to create a folder and after that I have to create a database in it by programatically. I have created folder and database but when I want to create a table in it, first I doesn't say anything (I guess it creates) but I cannot see the tables anywhere and if I will try for second time, it says  'There is already an object name like 'table_name' in the database.

And here is my code:

```
public void CreateFolder(string folderName)
{
    int count = 0;
    string path = "C:\\Users\\aabbccdd\\Documents\\";
    string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
    foreach (var item in folders)
    {

        string dosyaAdi = item.Substring(path.Length);
        if (dosyaAdi.Length >= folderName.Length)
        {
            if (folderName == item.Substring(path.Length, folderName.Length))
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
    }


public void CreateSqlDatabase(string filename)
{
    string databaseName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
    using (var connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(
        "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=master; Integrated Security=true;User Instance=True;"))
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText =
                        String.Format("CREATE DATABASE {0} ON PRIMARY (NAME={0}, FILENAME='{1}')", databaseName, filename);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Database başarılı bir şekilde oluşturuldu.", "Database", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    btn_forward.Visible = true;

                    command.CommandText =
                        String.Format("EXEC sp_detach_db '{0}', 'true'", databaseName);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();



                    command.CommandText = String.Format("IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='cftc_fabrika') alter table cftc_fabrika alter column asuman varchar(100) ELSE create table cftc_fabrika(asuman varchar(100))");

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }

            }

            catch (SystemException ex) // Change exception type based on your underlying data provider
            {
                if (ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("already exists. choose a different database name"))
                {
                    var match = Regex.Match(ex.Message, "LDATABASE '(.*)' already exists.",
                        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                        String dbFileName = match.Groups[1].Value;
                        Process p = new Process();
                        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                        p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                        p.StartInfo.FileName = String.Format("{0}/Tools/SSEUtil.exe",
                            Environment.CurrentDirectory);
                        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
                        p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-d \"{0}\"", dbFileName);

                        p.Start();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hata" + ex.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: "i can not see the tables anywhere" - how are you checking this? Through code here, e.g. you can't select from the table? Or attaching SQL Server Management Studio? Or something else?

Comment: You got to switch to your database after creating it or else you will create the table on the master database... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.changedatabase(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have created another windows form application and add localdatabase in it like add existing item, and checking from there, if it creates or not? Is it a wrong way to check it ?

Comment: How can i create the table on master database ?

Comment: "How can i create the table on master database ?" By mistake.

Comment: @Rup do you have any idea??

Answer (score 0):

This way you can create the database and then create the table by using this database Name

```
   String str;
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection ("Server=localhost;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master");

        str = "CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase ON PRIMARY " +
            "(NAME = MyDatabase_Data, " +
            "FILENAME = 'C:\\MyDatabaseData.mdf', " +
            "SIZE = 2MB, MAXSIZE = 10MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%) " +
            "LOG ON (NAME = MyDatabase_Log, " +
            "FILENAME = 'C:\\MyDatabaseLog.ldf', " +
            "SIZE = 1MB, " +
            "MAXSIZE = 5MB, " +
            "FILEGROWTH = 10%)";

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
        try 
        {
            myConn.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("DataBase is Created Successfully", "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        finally
        {
    if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        myConn.Close();
    }
        }
```

For Table Do this:-

```
var commandStr= "If not exists (select name from sysobjects where name = 'Customer') CREATE TABLE Customer(First_Name char(50),Last_Name char(50),Address char(50),City char(50),Country char(25),Birth_Date datetime)";

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandStr, con))
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

[Blog For you](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/307283/how-to-create-a-sql-server-database-programmatically-by-using-ado-net)

Comment: If i do like this one it can not open the connection.

Comment: I can't understand your last comment, can you please rephrase it :-)? @AsumanAytimur

Comment: Sorry for my english :) Directory lookup for the file "C:\Users\asuman.aytimur\Documents\DENEME.mdf" failed with the operating system error 5(Erişim engellendi.).
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

Comment: Server=.\\sqlexpress i did like this, because if i do like server= local it couldnt open sql connection.

Comment: After creating database and tables without error, i am creating a new windows form application and add the local database on it like Add Existing Item and  i can not see the added tables on it.

Comment: so whats the problem in windows application u r able to connect that database?

Comment: Yes i am able to connect the database but when i click the tables it is empty

Comment: I didnt insert any data, just created table as you send me 'Customer'

Comment: table isnt empty, there is no table :D

Comment: ok whenever you are executing query ExecuteNonQuery will return some Value please debug it and tell me what its returning put this int result=command.ExecuteNonQuery();
and check what you are getting in result and tell me

Comment: it returns -1 value